# Python WinError 32 The process cannot access the file because it is used by another process

Tags: python-3.x, delete-file, traceback

I have a problem using the google drive api to upload files. After uploading i want to delete the uploaded file from my folder but i get this error:

[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is used by another process

Here the code:

```
        if str(current_hour) in hour_folder_names:
            # upload files
            current_hour_folder_id = hour_folder_id_dic[str(current_hour)]
            name_list = image_path.split('/')
            print(name_list[len(name_list) - 1])
            file_metadata = {
                'name': name_list[len(name_list) - 1],
                'parents': [current_hour_folder_id]
            }
            chunk_size = 256 * 1024
            media = MediaFileUpload(image_path, mimetype='image/png', chunksize=chunk_size,  resumable=True)
            request = service.files().create(
                body=file_metadata,
                media_body=media,
                fields='id'
            )
            #wait for upload has finished
            response = None
            while response is None:
                status, response = request.next_chunk()
            os.remove(image_path)
```

if i use the os.remove function outside of that function it works. using it in that function gives me that error.

I implemented that to wait until the upload finished but that didn't work.

```
response = None
            while response is None:
                status, response = request.next_chunk()
os.remove(image_path)
```